# IOS Image Rotational Scrolling

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have chart images that are conical projections. Whenever the chart position moves, I need to rotate the chart. Imagine viewing a globe from above. The change in rotation is generally less than 1 degrees for a full screen of scrolling.

I am currently doing this in an image view within a scroll view, redrawing the images when the position changes. Any small change in position requires a complete redraw.

Is there a way to have IOS rotate the images within the layer without having to redraw them.

I am imaging something like in the maps app where you can scroll-rotate your course.

Another way of looking at it would be to have something like a scroll view that can scroll up/down or rotate its contents around an axis that may be way off the top of the screen.

Comment: What do you mean by rotating the image? Are you just using 2d UIImage? Are you using some sort of OpenGL or Quartz2D?

Comment: Rotate the image like spin a globe. I am using UIImage now. I draw imagines into the UI image then put the image into a UIImageView. I could change.